# Writing an application event handler

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write an unhandled exception event handler as in this question
[Catching application crash events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519161/catching-application-crash-events)

But the code as given won't compile, giving the message

```
error BC30590: Event 'UnhandledException' cannot be found.
```

How to fix?  Do I need to import something (I'm new to VB) - if so then what?

```
Partial Friend Class MyApplication
    Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException
        MsgBox(e.Exception.Message + vbNewLine + e.ToString())
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Did you follow the steps where I said to enable the Application Framework and click the View Application Events button?

Comment: The `enable application framework` checkbox is checked, and I pasted the code from your answer into `ApplicationEvents.vb` which appeared when I clicked `view application events`.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes.  If that's what you did, it should have worked.  Can you please edit your question to show the entire contents of that file?

Comment: Done.  I presume MyApplication is ok - I should't change that (my application as I see it consists of just a single class called Form1)

Comment: That's the entire file?  That isn't wrapped in a `Namespace My`/`End Namespace` block?

Comment: Yes.  No namespace block.  The app functionality sits in form1.vb which contains event handlers for a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the `MyApplication` partial class to work, it must be in the same namespace as the primary `MyApplication` class.  If it's not, that means that you are just creating a whole new `MyApplication` class which doesn't include that event.  To fix your code, make sure that the partial class is in the `My` namespace, like this:

```
Namespace My
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication
        Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException
            ' ...
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```